# apache2 is directing to wrong path when using https for sub domains

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, redirect, apache2

I have an ssl wildcard cert (letsencrypt) for example.de & *.example.com.

My 000-default.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerName example.de
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://example.de/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cloud.example.de
    ServerAdmin info@example.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud.example.de
    Redirect permanent / https://cloud.example.de/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.de
    ServerAdmin info@example.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.example.de
    Redirect permanent / https://dev.example.de/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.de
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/privkey.pem
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

dev.example.de & cloud.example.de has the wildcard ssl certificate and redicts both to the html directory??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luTYu.png)

Same happend when I use this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSqU7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your DocumentRoot in the ssl virtualhost is pointing to that path `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`